# vim YouCompleteMe not working on MacVim

Tags: javascript, node.js, vim, macvim

I am a huge fan of vim and I've been using it for the last two years. I'm quite new to web programming. Currently I'm working on Node.js and I wanted some additional plugins which can help me learn this new technology.  I installed tern_for_js and YouCompleteMe using Vundle. I also compiled YCM, but I don't see any auto-completion or javascript support. Here is my .vimrc:

```
syntax on

set number
set laststatus=2
set nocompatible
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=2
set smartindent

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'bling/vim-airline'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'ternjs/tern_for_vim'
Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
call vundle#end()

:map <F2> :echo 'Current time is ' . strftime('%c')<CR>

set guifont=ProggyCleanTT:h18
colorscheme torte
NERDTree
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong. Or did I miss something? Is there some extra configuration that have to be made?

Comment: The same question was also posted at [vi SE](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/vim-youcompleteme-not-working).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following lines are crucial for vundle to work correctly

```
filetype off                  " required
```

put it before

```
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
```

Turn it back on after vundle end

```
call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on
```

Also you don't need `:map` , `map` is fine.

Comment: Also, put this at the top of your configuration file. Otherwise you risk plugins overwriting your settings.

Comment: @rohankanojia: Did this answer help to solve the issue for you?